Is it possible in Haskell to derive a type from a value of another type so that any two different values result in various types?
Here is the context:
newtype A = A Integer deriving (Eq)

data PairOfA = PairA A A deriving (Eq)

mkPairOfA :: [A] -> A -> A -> Maybe PairOfA
mkPairOfA as a1 a2 =
  if a1 `elem` as && a2 `elem` as
    then Just (PairA a1 a2)
    else Nothing

as1 = [A 1, A 2, A 3]

as2 = [A 1, A 2, A 4]

pair1 = mkPairOfA as1 (A 1) (A 2)

pair2 = mkPairOfA as2 (A 1) (A 2)

main :: IO ()
main = do print $ pair1 == pair2

Here is the output in the terminal:
ghci> main
True

Question: Is there a way to somehow distinguish pair1 and pair2 by the fact that they are "related" to different lists? I could've defined the PairA constructor to assume three parameters instead of two, i.e., with the list parameter. However, I don't want my library's potential users to have to store a possibly long list within each pair, especially if they will work with many "pairs."
In the imperative paradigm, for example, in some OOP languages like Java or C++, I would use a reference or the pointer and put it in each pair without a second thought. What could be an alternative in Haskell? If I were to pick one, I would be fascinated to capture it on the type level. But if it is impossible, I would appreciate any other conventional workarounds.
Edit:
I've ended up with the following:
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

import GHC.TypeLits (Symbol)

newtype A = A Integer deriving (Eq, Show)

data As (label :: Symbol) = As [A]

data PairOfA (label :: Symbol) = PairA A A deriving (Eq, Show)

mkPairOfA :: As label -> A -> A -> Maybe (PairOfA label)
mkPairOfA (As as) a1 a2 =
  if a1 `elem` as && a2 `elem` as
    then Just (PairA a1 a2 :: PairOfA label)
    else Nothing

as1 = As [A 1, A 2, A 3] :: As "as1"

as2 = As [A 1, A 2, A 4] :: As "as2"

pair1 = mkPairOfA as1 (A 1) (A 2)

pair2 = mkPairOfA as2 (A 1) (A 2)

main :: IO ()
{-
• Couldn't match type ‘"as2"’ with ‘"as1"’
  Expected: Maybe (PairOfA "as1")
    Actual: Maybe (PairOfA "as2")
• In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘pair2’
  In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘pair1 == pair2’
  In a stmt of a 'do' block: print $ pair1 == pair2
-}
main = do print $ pair1 == pair2


Put the list in the pair. Don't worry, just like what you would do in Java or C++, this just stores a reference to the real thing, so it's equally cheap (or equally expensive, if you prefer).
data PairWithSourceList = PWSL A A [A] deriving (Eq)

Of course, the Eq instance will still have to compare the full lists for equality. But there really is no good way to avoid that.
The part of your question about tracking this at the type level generates the same answer as your other question about tracking such things at the type level.

Thank you. Could hashing be a solution so that we keep not the list but its hash? Wouldn't then equality checking be instant?

@Seeker Hashing has its own foibles. If you have two unequal lists and at least one of them is infinite, hashing is a severe pessimization -- it never finishes, whereas the standard Eq instance does. In the other direction, if you check the two hashes and they are equal, you still need to do a full equality check to verify that they aren't merely a hash collision. It is true that having two unequal hashes is a common case, and you may get a speed boost in that situation, but it's important to keep in mind the failure modes -- they will bite you if you don't (and may even if you do).

thank you again for your response.
I'm reflecting on using the Symbol kind to emulate a "namespace" (if that's the correct term). The idea is that when a user creates a list, they would "assign" it a "name." Then, using a "smart" constructor, the same "name" could somehow be associated with pairs created from this list. Does that make sense?
I wouldn't need to store the list's identifier within each pair, as doing so would feel unnatural since it wouldn't affect the behavior much. At the same time, this approach should still prevent messing things up. What do you think?

@Seeker It sounds like you're putting your trust in the user to use the Symbol mechanism correctly, i.e. trusting them to choose a unique Symbol for each list. If you trust your user with a protocol, why not trust them with the protocol "don't mix pairs from different lists", which makes your implementation job significantly simpler?

for example, if the user marks a value of an atomic type within my library, all the elements within a collection containing this value may "inherit" the label even if not typed explicitly. The label can then spread over the values of more complex types. Then, even if the user accidentally tries to mix the values that are not supposed to be mixed, for example, compare them, it will result not in False but a type error. Things like polymorphic equality, ignoring labels, or typecasting from one label to another might also be possible. I'm a newbie and just experimenting :)

In addition to my reasons above (I'm not sure they make sense, though ), is there a way I can make the user assign the label for the atomic types of my library? At any rate, it is no big deal: one can interpret no label as a label itself (default "namespace").

@Seeker Let me say again that the correct way to do this is described in the paper Ghosts of Departed Proofs. The alternative "don't try to prevent this kind of bug at all" is also a VERY strong contender in my opinion.

I'm reading this paper now. That's a very clever way to get things done. Thank you for the reference. And it is indeed what I felt I had to ensure within my library.
